# Double integral with logarithms

Tags: integration

**Faster method to calculate the exact solution of the following integral (based on the ideas of Fedor Petrov: https://mathoverflow.net/users/4312/fedor-petrov, Double integral with logarithms, URL (version: 2019-04-15): https://mathoverflow.net/q/328126):**

$$J\equiv \int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\ln x-\ln y}{x-y}}}dxdy .$$

Since
 $$f\left( x,y \right)=\frac{\ln x-\ln y}{x-y}=f\left( y,x \right),$$
the surface $f\left( x,y \right) $ is symmetric with respect to the bisector plane $x = y$; so,

$$\frac{J}{2}=\int_{0}^{1}{dx\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{\ln x-\ln y}{x-y}}}dy.$$

With the change of variable$$y\equiv tx,\ t\in \left( 0,\ 1 \right),$$
the integral
$$\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{\ln x-\ln y}{x-y}}dy,$$
is transformed into the following one that does not depend on $x$,
$$ I\equiv -\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,}dt.$$

The integration on the unit square $(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0,1)$ is reduced to the integration on the triangle $(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1).$

To solve the integral $I$ we will carry out the new change of variable,
$$s\equiv 1-t,$$
by which $I$ is transformed into the integral that defines the *dilogarithm*, whose value for $s = 1$ coincides with the *Riemann zeta* $\zeta \left( 2 \right)$,whose value is well known:

$$I=\int_{1}^{0}{\frac{\ln \left( 1-s \right)}{s}\,}ds=\text{L}{{\text{i}}_{2}}\left( 1 \right)=\zeta \left( 2 \right)=\frac{{{\pi }^{2}}}{6}.$$
Therefore, the solution to the proposed integral is
$$J=\frac{{{\pi }^{2}}}{3}.$$

**Note**. I've tried it by *polylogarithmic* transformations, but I couldn't get the result $\frac{{{\pi }^{2}}}{3}.$

Comment: MSE is a right place for such type questions. Both Maple and Mathematica confirm $ \frac{\pi ^2}{3}$.

Comment: I do not think this is such a bad question. I would not expect even every research mathematician to come up with the answer right away. So I vote not to close.

Comment: @user64494 what is a general strategy: when you have an integral which you do not know how to calculate, how should you decide between MSE and MO?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: First of all, exact closed-form integration is old-fashioned math from the 19th century.  In most  math applications we need the numerical value of an integral.

Comment: @user64494 being the author of several papers devoted to exact closed-form integration, I feel so old now.

Comment: Learning techniques for a problem here could be illuminating (depending on ...) for future purposes of integration or summation that they relate to or approximated by (if you are into numerical values). Plus, cute arguments are aesthetically pleasing ...

Comment: Closing a question doesn't mean it's bad. Also doesn't mean it would be solved right away by any research mathematician.

Comment: Everyone is entitled to use their own criteria. But I think these are useful indicators that the question deserves to stay open. Here's a third: a very reputable MO-member has provided an answer that has received many upvotes.

Comment: First of all, I apologize to those who believe that my question is not appropriate for this forum.
I sincerely appreciate all the comments on the matter, but very especially to Fedor Petrov who has given me a very quick response, with a truly amazing conciseness.
I would just like to add some annotations (see the edited question) for those who have felt interested in the question.

Comment: It would be nice if you would credit Fedor in your post. Anyone not wading through the comments would think the solution you give was entirely your work. In addition, you have the option of "accepting" Fedor's answer by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: Of course; I had already thought about quoting Fedor Petrov, but I had not had time to do it until now (I realized after editing the question for the last time). The confusion is produced by confusing the comment I made in response to other comments, believing that this would be reflected in the post. In any case, I appreciate the warning.

Answer (score 15):

By symmetry we have $J/2=\int_0^1 dx \int_0^x f(x, y) dy$ where $f(x, y) $ is your integrand. Integrating against $y$ for fixed $x$ we denote $y=tx$, $t$ varies from 0 to 1 and the integral against $y$ reads as $-\int_0^1 \frac{\log t} {1-t}dt$. It does **not** depend on $x$ and is well known to be equal to $\pi^2/6$ (you may use the geometric progression expansion $\frac{1}{1 - t} =\sum_{n>0 } t^{n-1}$ and integrate term-wise to get $\sum 1/n^2$).